# Deleting entire row if text is found at any column of the sequential file

Tags: sorting, mainframe, jcl

Using SORT, is it possible to delete a record if a supplied text is in the row?  For instance, in the following records any record that contains the text "record" would not be copied.

Suppose:

```
123456abcdrecord123
111recordaaaaaaaaaa
recordjjjjjj1111111
11111111111abcccccc
```

So my output should be:

```
11111111111abcccccc
```

Can anyone suggest the right control cards for SORT?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
OMIT COND=(1,19,SS,EQ,C'record')
```

[Substring search for INCLUDE and OMIT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=records-substring-search-include-omit)